# Spring Boot Enable Specific Embedded Database HSQL over Derby

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hsqldb

I'm trying to deploy My application on weblogic server, My application has an in-memory DB and since I use HSQLDB for JUNIT, I want to keep HSQL as my in-memory DB(primarily a slight better performance over derby). Since weblogic has already derby, when I try to deploy the application, The derby is getting started rather than HSQL. On Preliminary investigation I find that Since Derby is define above HSQL in EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.java, Derby database is being started first. Is there any specific configuration, where I can explicitly embedded database type to HSQL rather than allowing spring boot to start database based on library/classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First try I can think of is to remove Derby from class path and leave there only HSQL. [Spring Boot docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-auto-configuration):

> If HSQLDB is on your classpath, and you have not manually configured
>   any database connection beans, then we will auto-configure an
>   in-memory database.

If that's not an option, you can specify

1. [connection type for Hibernate (JPA)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-initialize-a-database-using-hibernate):

> An embedded database is detected by looking at the Connection type: hsqldb, h2 and derby are embedded, the rest are not.

2. HSQL explicitly as primary data source:

   ```
   @Configuration
   public class DataSourceConfig {
       @Bean
       public DataSource dataSource() {
           return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
              .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
              .build();
       }
   }
   ```
3. define `spring.datasource.type` property

Comment: Yes, I did use 2 option as an workaround, However, I would prefer 3 option, which doesn't work, spring.datasource.type is not being considered

Comment: I'm accepting answer, as in spring-boot, if anything you do-not like create bean that override which is second option.